# VBA macro crashing

Tags: vba, excel, macros

I try to create a macro, but when it launch itself, excel don't handle it and crash.

Here is the macro:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
Dim i As Integer
Dim sous As Integer
If Not IsEmpty(Cells(4, 2)) And IsNumeric(Cells(4, 2).Value) And Not IsEmpty(Cells(4, 3)) And IsNumeric(Cells(4, 3).Value) Then
    For i = Cells(4, 3).Value To Cells(4, 2).Value
        sous = i - Cells(4, 3).Value
        Cells(5 + sous, 4).Value = i
    Next i
MsgBox "Yataaaah"
End If
End Sub
```

The problem is the line `Cells(5 + sous, 4).Value = i` because if I put it on comment, it work.

Anyone have any idea why excel doesn't handle it?

Thank you very much.
Ps: I'm on mac and I'm using Excel 15.19.1

Comment: What is the error you get?  Have you confirmed that `sous` and `i` can never exceed the limit of a VBA Integer (32767)?  Without seeing examples of the data you are working with or even the error you are getting it's quite difficult to provide meaningful help

Comment: I enter in both cells 50 and 40 ,and i took car of witch one is the max and witch one is the min, so no they can't be out of limit.
Here is the error : " We've closed Excel because we met a problem. Sorry for the inconvenient. Excel will try to take back your work unsaved but it may be lost." (something like that) No error number or something similar.

Comment: please provide a [mcve]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to turn off events.  The reason Excel crashes is that the selection change event changes a value that fires the selection change event. It get's stuck in an endless loop.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim sous As Integer
    If Not IsEmpty(Cells(4, 2)) And IsNumeric(Cells(4, 2).Value) And Not IsEmpty(Cells(4, 3)) And IsNumeric(Cells(4, 3).Value) Then
        For i = Cells(4, 3).Value To Cells(4, 2).Value
            sous = i - Cells(4, 3).Value
            Cells(5 + sous, 4).Value = i
        Next i
        MsgBox "Yataaaah"
    End If

    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

Comment: It might also be a good idea to check if the change that was made is relevant, i.e. if it was in Cells(4,3), Cells(4,2) or Column(4) (row 5+)